# Questionable small white spots on panda plant

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, indoors, leaves

I’m not too sure when these spots came up. Did a quick google search and the first results says that it could be mealybugs, but I don’t see any actual bugs on the plant or in the soil. A few other answers I found says it could be cold spots, dried up water on the plant or some other plant disease.

In terms of watering, it’s watered when the soil is dry and we water directly into the pot. It’s on the windowsill so it gets plenty of sun and it’s also placed near an AC that is on occasionally (every other day for about 30 minutes to an hour)

[image: panda plant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photo doesn't magnify well so its not possible to see clearly, but the white 'spots' do appear to be mealybug. Mealybugs look white because they cover themselves in a white deposit, so the white 'spots' are likely actual bugs. Use a Q tip dipped in isopropyl alcohol and swab each white area with it. Further info here https://succulentplantcare.com/help-there-are-insects-on-my-succulents/

Comment: I'm guessing it's in the beginning stages of it's growing lifecycle since it isn't moving when I touch it. Is there a way to confirm that it is mealybugs or should I not take a risk and swab it.

Comment: Just swab the white spots, before it gets worse! spreads like wildfire, best treated immediately. You could check with a magnifying glass first if you're not sure...

Comment: Do you recommend any % isopropyl alcohol?

Comment: 70% isopropyl  or just use rubbing alcohol